# How can i get the value of a datagrid cell on the dataGrid1_BeginningEdit Event?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to check if the value of a datagrid cell is null when i use the dataGrid1_BeginningEdit Event to stop the event.

code is as follows, i can use '(((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text' when im doing 'dataGrid2_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)' but not for the below.

```
    private void dataGrid2_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        int column = dataGrid2.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
        int row = dataGrid2.SelectedIndex;

        if (((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text == null)
            return;
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will help you....

```
    private void DataGrid_BeginningEdit(
        object sender,
        Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = GetCellValue(((DataGrid) sender).CurrentCell) == null;
    }

    private static object GetCellValue(DataGridCellInfo cell)
    {
        var boundItem = cell.Item;
        var binding = new Binding();
        if (cell.Column is DataGridTextColumn)
        {
            binding
              = ((DataGridTextColumn)cell.Column).Binding
                    as Binding;
        }
        else if (cell.Column is DataGridCheckBoxColumn)
        {
            binding
              = ((DataGridCheckBoxColumn)cell.Column).Binding
                    as Binding;
        }
        else if (cell.Column is DataGridComboBoxColumn)
        {
            binding
                = ((DataGridComboBoxColumn)cell.Column).SelectedValueBinding
                     as Binding;

            if (binding == null)
            {
                binding
                  = ((DataGridComboBoxColumn)cell.Column).SelectedItemBinding
                       as Binding;
            }
        }

        if (binding != null)
        {
            var propertyName = binding.Path.Path;
            var propInfo = boundItem.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            return propInfo.GetValue(boundItem, new object[] {});
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @wpf-it-- unable to find CurrentCell property for Datagrid.

Comment: I dont know why you cannot find it but you can alternatively use DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e object. It has e.Column and e.Row.DataContext properties to your benefit. In the GetCellValue() call, boundItem  would now be e.Row.DataContext  and cell.Column will be e.Column.

Answer (score 4):

I found a different approach:

```
ContentPresenter cp = (ContentPresenter)e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row);
YourDataType item = (YourDataType)cp.DataContext;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
(e.EditingEventArgs.Source as TextBlock).Text
```

Comment: What's your column type? DataGridTextColumn or something else? If you used the above coed what issue you facing?

Comment: The `EditingEventArgs.Source` seems to be always `null` for me.

Comment: @RohitVats Would you have time for a suggestion/comment on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61688520/1232087)

Answer (score 1):

```
var row = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
var value = row["ColumnName"];
//now you can do whatever you want with the value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dataGrid2_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGrid2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value == null)
                {}
        }
```

Comment: Sorry it's a Datagrid i have, not a datagrid view. Do you know how to do this for a datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [`DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridbeginningediteventargs.aspx), they contain a property `Column` and `Row` which you can use to select the cell from the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

This is lot simpler then some of the other working answers:

```
    private void DataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        string content = (e.EditingEventArgs.Source as TextBlock).Text;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```