# On a Button Click, making multiple cells editable in a selected row of a ReadOnly DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

**Question**: In a `ReadOnly` DataGrid, how can we place multiple cells, in a selected row, in Edit mode?

In following `ReadOnly` DataGrid, the `btnEdit_Click` event (shown below) successfully places the `FirstName` column cell of selected row in the edit mode. But I need both `FirstName` and `LastName` column cells in the edit mode. If I enclose the entire code of that event in a `for loop` as `for (int i=2; i <=3; i++){...}` only the last cell (`LastName`) column gets the edit mode.

**Remark**:

1. All other rows have to stay in `ReadOnly` mode when user is editing the selected row.
2. I'm using [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) for db operations (e.g. MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = db.Customers.ToList(); etc) and `.NET Core 3.1`, `VS2019` latest version.
3. No `MVVM` is involved.
4. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14815951/1232087) is a similar post but for a column (not for row).
5. For brevity, only two columns are shown. Real scenario has more than two columns.

**DataGrid**:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,25,0,0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Visibility="Collapsed" Binding="{Binding CustomerId}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Code**:

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell dataGridCell;
    MyDataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo((sender as Button).DataContext, MyDataGrid.Columns[2]);
    var cellContent = MyDataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.GetCellContent(MyDataGrid.CurrentCell.Item);
    if (cellContent != null)
    {
        dataGridCell = (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;
        dataGridCell.IsEditing = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only place one cell in edit mode at a time no matter the DataGrid's `IsReadOnly` property is True or False.

If you want to allow users to edit the cells of a specific row after clicking the "Edit" button, you may refer to the below code:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,25,0,0"
          SelectedCellsChanged="MyDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged" SelectionUnit="Cell">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Visibility="Collapsed" Binding="{Binding CustomerId}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
    private Customer _editableCustomer;
    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _editableCustomer = (Customer)MyDataGrid.SelectedCells.First().Item;
    }

    private void MyDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedCells.First().Item == _editableCustomer)
            GetDataGridCell(MyDataGrid.SelectedCells.First()).IsEditing = true;
    }

    public static DataGridCell GetDataGridCell(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
    {
        var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
        if (cellContent != null)
            return (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;

        return null;
    }
```

However, I personally would not do this. I would set the DataGrid's `IsReadOnly` property to False and add an event handler for DataGrid's `BeginningEdit` event. Then I could do whatever I want in the event handler before the user edits the rows.

Comment: I noticed `MyDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(...)` event is called before `btnEdit_Click(...)` event. And, at that time since _editableCustomer is null, the `if (e.AddedCells.First().Item == _editableCustomer)` statement in  `MyDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(...)` is missed - hence no cell is placed in edit mode.

Comment: Yes. After clicking the edit button, _editableCustomer will be set. It allows users to click and edit the other cells of the same row.

Comment: In regard to your other suggestion about using `BeginningEdit` event. In this event, how can we make all rows, other than the selected one, `ReadOnly`? My requirement is: All other rows have to stay in ReadOnly mode when user is editing the selected row.